# How to get max and min of mysql column from another related table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

this is my database tables

- Lists
- Requests
- products

Every request has one product and every list has many requests
now i want to get the min and max price/size for the products in list X , how can i achieve this with Laravel Elequent  ?

Lists table

```
+----+----------+
| id | user_id  |
+====+==========+
| 1  | 1        |
+----+----------+
| 2  | 1        |
+----+----------+
| 3  | 2        |
+----+----------+
```

Requests table

```
+----+-------------+----------+
| id | product_id  | list_id  |
+====+=============+==========+
| 1  | 1           | 1        |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 2  | 1           | 1        |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 3  | 2           | 2        |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

Products table

```
+----+-------+------+-------+
| id | price | size | other |
+====+=======+======+=======+
| 1  | 110   | 10   | test  |
+----+-------+------+-------+
| 2  | 130   | 12   | test  |
+----+-------+------+-------+
| 3  | 100   | 24   | test  |
+----+-------+------+-------+
| 4  | 200   | 16   | test  |
+----+-------+------+-------+
```

Comment: have you tried to first do this in MySQL as a query and also can you post what you have tried so far? I would first advice you to do this in MySQL. Formulating to an eloquent query from that is easier.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the min and max price/size for the products in list X

```
$maxSize = Product::whereHas('request.list', function($q) use($listId) {
    $q->where('list.id', $listId);
})
->max('size');

$minSize = Product::whereHas('request.list', function($q) use($listId) {
    $q->where('list.id', $listId);
})
->min('size');
```

Do the same for the min and max price.

Comment: is there any other way to get the same result using Lists or Requests model ?